# csv data dump in mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi I need to copy data from  a csv file into a mysql table.Copy of data has to be remotely.My csv file is not present on the db server.Any idea how to do it.

I can do locally file copy from csv but not from different machine.

thanks

Comment: Read and Parse the file, then loop through the parsed data and do INSERT/UPDATE on your database.  You could also use a tool that can read a csv file to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you have many options. If you have phpMyAdmin or other sql manager - it is easier variant. Else you should copy the file locally and use mysql shell tools to import the data.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) . By using the LOCAL option, you specify that it's a local file and not a file located on the db server. The FIELDS TERMINATD BY and other options lets you adjust to the format of your .csv file